# Missing right paranthesis in Crystal report with Oracle

Tags: crystal-reports

I have the following query to get the data between dates. If I execute with values in Oracle then it is returning the data. But while developing the crystal report it is throwing missing parenthesis. I was stuck and client already started screaming. Please help out.. :(

Parameters

P_GEN_REPT_ID : STRING

P_START_DATE : DATE :MM/DD/YYYY

P_END DATE : DATE :MM/DD/YYYY

P_KPI_ONLY : STRING

P_RLTM_EQP_TYPE : STRING

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.f_cd
FROM realtime_equip_installations a
WHERE a.ep_a_num IN
(SELECT codes
FROM scsi_driving_lists s
WHERE s.rpt_run_id = '{?p_gen_rpt_run_id}')
AND instr(nvl('{?p_rltm_eqp_type}',
a.eqp_typ_cd),
a.eqp_typ_cd) > 0
AND (nvl(a.eqp_inst_dt,TO_DATE('{?p_start_date}','MM/DD/YYYY')) 
BETWEEN  TO_DATE('{?p_start_date}','MM/DD/YYYY') 
AND TO_DATE('{?p_End_date}','MM/DD/YYYY'))
AND ('{?p_kpi_only}' = 'N' OR a.eqp_pe_vrfy_flg = 'Y')
AND A.EQP_TYP_CD != 'MPFM'
UNION
SELECT w.f_cd
FROM multiphase_flowmeters m,
pipelines  p,
realtime_equip_installations a,
well_master                  w
WHERE p.ds_node_id = to_char(m.mpfm_num)
AND a.mpfm_num = m.mpfm_num
AND w.ep_a_num = p.us_node_id
AND p.us_node_typ_cd = 'WELL'
AND p.ds_node_typ_cd = 'MPFM'
AND p.us_node_id IN
(SELECT codes
FROM scsi_driving_lists s
WHERE s.rpt_run_id = '{?p_gen_rpt_run_id}')
AND instr(nvl('{?p_rltm_eqp_type}',
a.eqp_typ_cd),
a.eqp_typ_cd) > 0
AND (nvl(a.eqp_inst_dt,TO_DATE('{?p_start_date}','MM/DD/YYYY')) 
BETWEEN TO_DATE('{?p_start_date}','MM/DD/YYYY') AND 
TO_DATE('{?p_End_date}','MM/DD/YYYY'))
AND ('{?p_kpi_only}' = 'N' OR a.eqp_pe_vrfy_flg = 'Y')
ORDER BY f_cd
```

Its showing missing right parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Each of the inner queries starting with:

WHERE a.ep_a_num IN (SELECT ...

and

IN (SELECT codes ...

needs a closing parenthesis

Comment: (SELECT codes
FROM scsi_driving_lists s
WHERE s.rpt_run_id = '{?p_gen_rpt_run_id}') already closed the parenthesis
 IN
       (SELECT CODES
          FROM SCSI_DRIVING_LISTS S
         WHERE S.RPT_RUN_ID = '{?P_GEN_RPT_RUN_ID}')
Here also Closed